# How to get a token to read (only read, not write) from raw.githubusercontent.com/org/repo/commit/file?

Tags: github, oauth, oauth-2.0, access-token, github-api

I am looking to use an access token to read raw files from github. In a Dockerfile I have:

```
ENV github_token='ACU7xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxKM'
ADD "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cm/go-api/master/go.mod?token=$github_token"  .
```

I am trying to figure out the minimum permissions I need to read the file from the url. In this image are the permissions:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

1. Does anyone know the minimum permissions necessary to read the file from the url? I can't figure out even which one is the crucial permission.
2. I hear that using access tokens in the URL is deprecated. Does anyone know of a non-interactive way of authenticating?

Comment: For example, here is the notice: https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-10-deprecating-auth-through-query-param/  but how can we use this header with the Docker ADD command?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know the minimum permissions necessary to read the file from the url? I can't figure out even which one is the crucial permission.

It depends on whether the URL is a public or private repository. I gather you're referring to a private repository here, and so the minimum scope needed is `repo`.

> I hear that using access tokens in the URL is deprecated. Does anyone know of a non-interactive way of authenticating?

The [link](https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-10-deprecating-auth-through-query-param/) in your comment outlines how you should pass in the access token:

> Instead, you should send the token in the header:
>
> `curl -H 'Authorization: token my_access_token' https://api.github.com/user/repos`

Regarding this last part:

> but how can we use this header with the Docker ADD command?

Given you now need to pass in a header, you may need to `curl` the file inside the Dockerfile and add it as a local file.